# VBA Skipping First Matching Cell

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

The following code is skipping over the first "hit". In "Notes", a cell with "x" in column G will get pasted to the new sheet. However, the first row with an "x" is being excluded each time:

```
Sub Test()
For Each Cell In Sheets("Notes").Range("G:G")
If Cell.Value = "x" Then
    matchRow = Cell.Row
    Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Copy

    Sheets("Completed Conversions").Select
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Notes").Select
End If
Next
Sheets("Completed Conversions").Select
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you certain you don't have a trailing space on the first instance of `x` in the worksheet?  To account for that you could use `If Trim(Cell.Value) = "x"` and that would handle any leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: You didn't ask, but you can do your copy past on one line like so: `Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Copy Sheets("Completed Conversions").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`. This is a much better approach than using select, although you still have an unqualified `Rows.Count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's need to Switch the `Select` between sheets in order to copy from one to the other.

Second, if you are to copy the entire row, instead of :

```
matchRow = Cell.Row
Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Copy
```

Use:

```
Cell.EntireRow.Copy
```

One last thing: instead of looping through the entire column G, just loop through all cells with values in them:

```
For Each Cell In Sheets("Notes").Range("G1:G" & Sheets("Notes").Cells(Sheets("Notes").Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)
```

Your entire code could be replaced with the code below:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets("Notes")
    For Each Cell In .Range("G1:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Trim(Cell.Value) = "x" Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Completed Conversions").Range("A" & Sheets("Completed Conversions").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next Cell
End With    

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.